# Recursive Sequence of Functions Question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

If you have a sequence of functions $y_{(n)}(x)$, where $n = 0,1,2,...$, which are defined recursively via the following relations:
\begin{align}
y_{(0)}&=0\\
y'_{(n+1)} &= y_{(1) }y_{(2)} y_{ (3)} ...y_{ (n+1)}\\
y_{(n+1)} (0) &= e ^{y_{(n)} (0)}
\end{align}

what would be $y_{(n+1)} (1)$ for n=100?

Comment: The product is from $1$ to $n+1$ or from $1$ to $n$? In the second case you can prove that all the $y_n$ are exponentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: as written, $y_1 = e^x$, $y_2(x) = e^{e^x}$, the equation
$$y_3' = e^x e^{e^x} y_3$$
can be easily solved because
$$\frac{de^{e^x}}{dx} = e^{e^x}e^x.$$
Can you see the pattern?